# R: row to column error while writing to DB

Tags: r, dataframe

Im using the below statement for converting rownames to column

```
library(tidyverse)
names(res) <- names(dt)[]
final<- imap(res, ~ .x %>% 
       as.data.frame %>% 
       select(!! .y := `Point Forecast`) %>% 
       rownames_to_column("Month_year")) %>% 
  reduce(inner_join, by = "Month_year")
```

and when i try to write the output to a db,
with

```
dbWriteTable(mycon, value = final , Database= 'mydb' ,name = "Rpredict", append = TRUE )
```

i receive an error as below:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1587: 42S22: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'Month_year'
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: I did, same error..

Comment: Can you check the schema of the table,.  May be it doesn't have the column

Comment: it does. but when i try with a new table name its working!